# Finding p-value when df and test stat is given. PLEASE HELP.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

For a chi-square goodness of fit test with 10 degrees of freedom, the test stat is 20.000, then how to find the p-value? In other words, what is ?: X^2?,10 = 20.000?

The X^2 table does not give the exact value of 20.000 when I look under 10 df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R gives the following value

```
> pchisq(q=20, df=10, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.02925269
```

You might want to compare this with the values you do have in you $\chi^2$ table to see if it is plausible.

Comment: I don't really understand how you got this number?

Comment: I asked my computer to work it out.  It looks consistent with the values at http://mnishikawa.iweb.bsu.edu/chisquare.jpg

Comment: More details on the R command [here.](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/pchisq)